# GeoJson in bingmap on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, geojson

How can I add a GeoJson in a bing map on Windows Phone 7 ?

On a gmap in a browser I make something like that :

```
var geo = new GeoJSON(data["content"]);
geo.setMap(myGMap);
```

How can I do something like that on WindowsPhone 7 on a bing map ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps control for Windows Phone 7 does not support GeoJSON natively.

That said, you will have to manage the downloading of your content and then loop on items to add the corresponding elements on the control.